# How to style a div to be fixed and be relative to surroundings

Tags: css

I have a website where I need the following functionality at the same time

1. The new header is fixed (using `position:fixed`)
2. The new header starts above the actual website (using `position:relative`)

Obviously I can't have both of these at once, but that is what I do want...

So, to explain in another way, what I when a header to be inserted into my webpage (via javascript) it doesn't obscure the website in any way, unless the user scrolls on the webpage, where the header remains 'on top' fixed.

Can this be done with CSS only where the following HTML can't be updated?

```
<body>
<header>
<nav>
//website
```

And after the javascript inserts the header

```
<body>
<div id="myInsertedDiv" class="whatCssGoesHere"></div>
<header>
<nav>
//website
```

https://jsfiddle.net/59orh8uf/4/

The fiddle shows a web page, where I insert this 'header' The header needs to be the first item in the webpage (at the top of the webpage). This is what is occurring on the jsfiddle, so the first challenge is fixed... All I need to do now is make it so when I scroll down, it remains on top.

I also need to point out, that the example is not the same for every website, and as such I can't touch the HTML of the header or anything else below

Comment: Sorry, your question is totally unclear. Code is fine. Can you show a working problem using [mcve]?

Comment: @PraveenKumar does this help?

Answer (score 0):

give your content as much margin as your headerheight is. This should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the header to be fixed and to be at the top of your page even though you scroll to the bottom of the page you simply insert this:

```
     body{
     margin-top: 100px; /* same as your height of your header */
     }

     header {   
     position: fixed; /* Set the header to fixed position */
     top: 0; /* Position the header at the top of the page */
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100px; /* just for example  */
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

you set the position `fixed` to `top: 0`, in order to have your header always in top of your page as you scroll down to the bottom.

Comment: If I do this, with it fixed, it will be "ontop" of the website

Comment: Exactly. As i said above, that i currently understand from your question, that you want the header to be on top without affect the rest of the page as you scroll to the bottom or to the top.

Comment: That is part of it yes. But when that "header" is added it needs to push the rest of the content down the page (as you'd expect if you inserted a p tag). I've updated my post with a jsfiddle

Comment: Ok if i understand correctly then you can add to the 'body' a padding-top or margin-top equal to the height of the 'header'. As for the header hold the top 0 at position fixed.

Comment: Yes... that would work but there is one more thing... this header may not always be added... if it's not added then I don't want a massive gap...

Comment: As for the gap, you can add the 'overflow' property. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the result you want by using position: fixed on your navbar and either top-padding on body or margin-top on header, both of witch should be the same as your navbar height.

But in this case I must point out the importance of [Writing JavaScript with accessibility](https://medium.com/@matuzo/writing-javascript-with-accessibility-in-mind-a1f6a5f467b9) in mind. Just so you don't write yourself in to a corner.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not use CSS as I don't think it was possible.

I used javascript and added an eventlistener on the scrollbar. If the scroll bar Y position is less than 1, then style.position = relative, else style.position = fixed